# Dompdf not getting css style during generating pdf in custom php

Tags: php, image, dompdf

I am trying to generate pdf from a html or php file using Dompdf. It's generating the pdf but it's not getting the proper css style of the page. Need help to resolve the issue. Anybody have the solution for me?

Here is the HTML/PHP output I want to convert into PDF

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u85Eq.png

Now I am getting this after converting PDF in Dompdf

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nqgrn.png

Check my dompdf code:

```
\<?php

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php'; 

use Dompdf\\Dompdf; 

$dompdf = new Dompdf(\['chroot' =\> \__DIR_\_\]);

$filename = 'F:/savePdf/doc.pdf';

$html = '\<link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" /\>';

$html .= file_get_contents("pdffile.html"); 

$dompdf-\>loadHtml($html); 

$dompdf-\>setPaper('A4', 'landscape'); 

$dompdf-\>render(); 

//$dompdf-\>stream("Test PDF", array("Attachment" =\> 0));

//$dompdf-\>stream();

$output = $dompdf-\>output();

file_put_contents($filename, $output);

?\>
```

Comment: It looks almost perfect to me. Please specify what you think is wrong, and even more important, we need to know what your HTML code is. Does it perhaps need an external CSS file?

Comment: Yeah, basically me too very much confused that what I am doing wrong. The css is working partially not completely.

Comment: Your comment didn't provide any additional information. Can you please give us the ability to help you by providing the content of the `pdffile.html` file in your question?

Comment: From what I can see it seems only the font you're using is not working?

Comment: (https://ascinate.in/projects/hiptips/savepdf/pdffile.html)  you can find the html and css viewing the source code.  This is the main file I need to convert into PDF.

Comment: Thank you. Your CSS specifies: `font-family: Calibri;`. This assumes that DomPDF supports this font, but it doesn't. See: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/About-Fonts-and-Character-Encoding

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Basically it's not about the font style only. Also the pdf not showing the proper line height and alignment of the tr and td.